# Disable Checkbox in React, Formik when its value from Server is returned false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, formik

I have a checkbox table that needs to be rendered based on a schema from the API:

The schema is the following:

```
  {
    "type": "item1",
    "name": "item1",
    "read": true,
    "write": true
  }
```

I have a checkbox component that holds the logic. See below:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

import { siblingFieldName } from './utils';

const PermissionsCheckbox = ({
  field: { name, value, onBlur },
  form: { setFieldValue },
  disable = false
}) => (
  <div>
    <input
      name={name}
      type="checkbox"
      value={value}
      checked={value}
      onChange={() => {
        if (name.includes('.write') && value === true) {
          setFieldValue(siblingFieldName(name, 'write'), false);
        }

        if (name.includes('.read') && value === false) {
          setFieldValue(siblingFieldName(name, 'read'), true);
        }
        setFieldValue(name, !value);
      }}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      disable={disable}
    />
  </div>
);

PermissionsCheckbox.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.object,
  form: PropTypes.object,
  disable: PropTypes.bool
};

export default PermissionsCheckbox;
```

In the main component, that renders the table I have the following logic. That displays the table and its respective checkboxes based on props:

```
  renderField = (field, index) => {
    const { keyField } = this.props;
    const { type, name, viewable, writable } = field;
    return (
      <div className="row" key={type}>
        <div className="col-4 my-1">{name}</div>
        {viewable && (
          <div className="col-2 my-1 text-center">
            <Field component={PermissionsCheckbox} name={`${keyField}.${index}.read`} />
          </div>
        )}
        {writable && (
          <div className="col-2 my-1 text-center">
            <Field component={PermissionsCheckbox} name={`${keyField}.${index}.write`} />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

I want the last checkbox which gets the value `write: false` from the API, to appear and be disabled.

The response from the server would be the following:

```
  {
    "type": "item5",
    "name": "item5",
    "read": true,
    "write": false
  }
```

Currently the logic says don't disable the write checkbox if `write: false`. I want it to show up but be disabled. I am using Formik for the forms.

I tried doing the following:

```
  renderField = (field, index) => {
    const { keyField } = this.props;
    const { type, name, readable, writable, disabled } = field;
    return (
      <div className="row" key={type}>
        <div className="col-4 my-1">{name}</div>
        {readable && (
          <div className="col-2 my-1 text-center">
            <Field component={PermissionsCheckbox} name={`${keyField}.${index}.read`} />
          </div>
        )}
        {writable ? (
          <div className="col-2 my-1 text-center">
            <Field component={PermissionsCheckbox} name={`${keyField}.${index}.write`} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="col-2 my-1 text-center">
            <Field
              component={PermissionsCheckbox}
              name={`${keyField}.${index}.write`}
              disabled={!disabled}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

But it doesn't work. It eithers shows all the checkboxes clickable or disabled based on the value of disabled. What am I doing wrong here?? Or is my logic wrong?

Comment: My first thought is that `readable` and `writable` are both falsy values when render runs, causing you to always render the component with `disable={!disabled}`. The fact that all components are disabled based on the value of `disabled`, it makes it even more possible. Without seeing what `field` is equal to when `renderField` runs, it's hard to say though. If `field` does not have keys of `readable` or `writable` when you destructure then this is for sure the problem.

Comment: Thnaks for the suggestiong. What I did and kinda solved the problem is this. I passed the `disabled` in props and now it works fine. Except for one thing. Now I get a warning for controlled and uncotrolled components when clicking. The error is about the `PermissionsCheckbox`. Should I pass the disabled as state there?? Or refactor it a bit...

Comment: If you aren't familiar with controlled versus uncontrolled components, I recommend doing some research on that before you dig yourself in too deep. Heres some links (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and (http://react.tips/checkboxes-in-react/)

Comment: No worries fix it... Just a typo.... thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: This is a good question, but tough to answer given your situation. Could you create a run-able example on a sandbox to demonstrate the problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/zKrK5YLDZ